# SgmlLinkExtractor stops on 3rd page

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Continuing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085725/stripping-of-the-addiotional-items-in-xpath) with SgmlLinkExtractor problems.

I'm trying to follow [the pages from here](http://tinyurl.com/od4q7xz)
while it seems to working and pulling all required items, crawler stops after 3rd page is parsed without any error message.

```
class AltaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "altaCra"
    allowed_domains = ["alta.ge"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://alta.ge/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297"
    ]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index.php\?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297&page=\d*", ))
        , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@class="table products cl"]//tr[@valign="middle"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            item = AltaItem()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('td[@class="compact"]/div[@class="cl-prod-name"]/a/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')    
            item["model"] = t.xpath('td[@class="compact"]/div[@class="cl-prod-name"]/a/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('td[@class="cl-price-cont"]//span[4]/text()').extract()

            items.append(item)

    return(items)
```

Comment: Typo? `allow=("index.php\?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297&page=\d*", )`

Comment: yes, made a typo while correcting my first question here. It still doesn't follow. I'll update the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links to next pages in the first page look like this:

```
http://alta.ge/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297&page=2
```

while links to next pages then look like:

```
http://alta.ge/index.php?category_id=297&dispatch=categories.view&page=8
```

So I suggest you use a different rule, targeting links with `name="pagination"` attribute, a property shared by all next page links:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@name="pagination"]',)),
         callback="parse_items", follow=True),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following rule (and adding `parse_start_urls`) will crawl through the 8 pages available without using Ajax. Let me see if I can get it to work so that it crawls through all 20 pages.

```
start_urls = [
    "http://alta.ge/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297"
    ]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index.php\?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=297&page=\d*", ))
        , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
       return self.parse_items(response)
```

Comment: Thanks @Talvalin for the new method :)